# Combinations and the product rule of probability

Tags: probability-theory

In my textbook I have the following problem:

In a bag containing 51 candies, 18 are white, 10 red, 7 oranges,
3 purple, 5 yellow, 2 blue and 6 green. Eight candies are drawn at random
(without replacement) from this bag.

(i) What is the probability of drawing exactly three white candies?

(ii) What is the probability of drawing three white, two red, one blue and
two green candies?

My answers are as follows:

i) For this question it seems to me that there would be (18 choose 3) * (8 choose 3) divided by (51 choose 8)

ii) For this one I am guessing that it would be:

((18 choose 3)*(8 choose 3) * (10 choose 2) * (5 choose 2) * (2 choose 1) * (3 choose 1) * (6 choose 2) * (2 choose 2)) all divided by (51 choose 8)

Is this reasoning correct?

Note: I am normally pretty good with mathjax, but I can't seem to find the combinations notation.

Comment: ${n}\choose {k}$ is {n}\choose {k}

Comment: @ZacharySelk i am having using this formula with fractions it is giving me the "ambiguous use of choose" error. Any tips? Also any tips on the problem itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the problem itself, we have for the first question:

We want $8$ candies. Out of these three must be white, pickable in $\binom{18}{3}$ ways. The rest of the five candies must not be white, so we want $5$ candies  out of $51-18=33$. So the answer is $\dfrac{\binom{18}{3}\binom{33}{5}}{\binom{51}{8}}$.

For the second question:

We can draw $3$ whites in $\binom{18}{3}$ ways.

We can draw $2$ reds in $\binom{10}{2}$ ways.

We can draw $1$ blues in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways.

We can draw $2$ greens in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways.

Hence the answer is $$\dfrac{\binom{18}{3}\binom{10}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{51}{8}}$$.

Hence, we get the result. Unfortunately the numbers above are too big to evaluate so I will leave the answer in this form.